# Obtain the text that a user is copying from a web page

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, is it possible to detect when a user is copying text from a web page, and then store the copied text in an array (without overriding the CTRL+V key combination, and without preventing the text from being copied)?

In other words, is it possible to detect a key combination without overriding the default behavior of that key combination?

Comment: No, I don't think you can. The access to the clipboard in Javascript is a security issue.

Comment: You can catch the keyboard with keyup, but you can't see what in the clipboard or send text to it.

Comment: I'm not trying to access the clipboard in any way. I'm only trying to detect the CTRL+C combination without overriding its default behavior. Also, it's possible to obtain the currently highlighted text using http://code.google.com/p/rangy

Comment: You can do this, create a sort of hack. Pseudo code: On control+C, push the selected text onto a stack. Do this for each control+C, on control+V, pop the last element off the stack. LIFO (Last in, first out)

Comment: Why don't you just try it. I think it should work. The default behavior remains unless u prevent it.

Comment: ah, ok. Yes, this can be done, but it's done differently by type of browser. Google `javascript select input text on focus` for hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `keyup` listener in jQuery and getting the event parameters `ctrlKey` and `keyCode`, then retrieving the selected text through `window.getSelection()`:

```
$(window).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 67) {
        alert("Text copied was: " + window.getSelection());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5kAG/1/

---

The default behaviour of the key strokes are not interfered with unless you `return false` in the listening function (or, in jQuery, `e.preventDefault()`, which in effect (and in code) does the same thing as `return false`).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily grab the copy & paste keystrokes, what you do with them is up to you.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 67) {
    console.log("CTRL + C");
  }

  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 86) {
    console.log("CTRL + V");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a library that catches copy/cut events and stores each piece of copied/cut text: https://github.com/jasonzissman/CopyMe.js.  It doesn't interfere with normal copy/cut behavior, it lets you set up handlers for the copy/cut events, and you can retrieve the entire array of all text copied/cut by the user.

At the moment, the accepted answer (catch the simultaneous 'ctrl' and 'c' keyup) seems to only work if the user presses both keys at the **exact** same time. Chrome (or perhaps Windows) seems to be more forgiving about the timing involved in ctrl + c, as you can still successfully copy data by hitting ctrl right before hitting c.  Even though Chrome (again, possibly a Windows thing) says you have successfully copied, the JavaScript event will fail to catch the action.

Example usage:

```
CopyMe.setCopyCallback(function(copiedText){
  // Do something here when text is copied
  alert(copiedText);
});
CopyMe.setCutCallback(function(cutText){
  // Do something here when text is cut
  alert(cutText);
});
var allCopiedCutText = CopyMe.getAllCopiedOrCutText();
var lastCopiedCutText = CopyMe.getLastCopiedOrCutText();
```